# create FlatList item. but it doesn't work on react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

Why is `FlatList` not working?

I am trying to get data from my API and view by `FlatList` but it is not working. I can see those values in the console, but not in the `FlatList`.

```js
**Home Page** 
   import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Text,TouchableOpacity,View,FlatList} from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
//import {VIEWDATA } from '../../src/action/type';
//import ViewData from '../../src/action/index'
import dataFetch from '../../src/action/index'
class AllData extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            values: [],
            b: [{id:1 ,name:'Turag'},{id:2,name:'Shagor'}],
            c:'av'
        }
    }
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
     return{
          values : props.val
     }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
         this.props.abc    
        //this.setState({values: this.props.val})
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return true;
      }
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
            <Text>View All Datas</Text>

            <FlatList
                data={this.state.b}
                renderItem={(i)=>{
                    <View>  <Text>{i.name}</Text> </View>
                   {console.log(i.name)}
                }}
                   keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />         
                <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={this.props.abc}
                >
                <Text>Submit</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
    return{
        val: state.arrayData
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return ({
        abc: () => {dispatch(dataFetch())}
    })
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(AllData)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Specifically, what does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using render item is wrong.

```
   renderItem={({item})=>{
           {console.log(item.name)}
            return (<View><Text>{item.name}</Text></View>)
    }}
```

Render item gets many parameters and to get the item you will have to use {item} which will give your access to the current item.

Also you are not returning anything from your function to render, The above code fixes the issues you have.

Comment: can i tell me how to show this data using forEach function

Comment: The preferred way is to use the map function, any specific reason to use for each?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return what you want to display on JSX

```
renderItem={(i)=>{
               return ( 
                     <View>  
                          <Text>{i.name}</Text> 
                     </View>
                     );
            }}
```